# ERROR ITMS-90596 / GM version of Xcode / Phonegap

Tags: ios, phonegap, ipa, application-loader

Can't figure out why I'm getting the below error. From a good phone gap build IPA file on submit to apple.

ERROR ITMS-90596: "Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at 'Payload/***.app/Assets.car' can't be processed. Rebuild your app, and all included extensions and frameworks, with the latest GM version of Xcode and resubmit."

Getting this error on submission of a PhoneGap Build IPA file. Have tried using Application loader 3.6 and 3.7. Also removed all spec on plug ins and removed the geolocation plugin. Deleted, rebuilt and recompiled with new dist cert and provision file as well. Also tried using client 8.0.0 and 8.1.1 (config XML extract below)

The following is more detail from the application loader log. I notice a 1102 error, but can't find much clear info on that either.

> [2018-11-28 09:39:13 PST]  DBG-X:   parameter
>   SoftwareMediaDescriptionFormat = binary
>
> [2018-11-28 09:39:13 PST]  DBG-X:   parameter ErrorCode = 1102
>
> [2018-11-28 09:39:13 PST]  DBG-X:   parameter
>   SoftwareMediaDescriptionThresholds =
>   {in-app-purchase-content={extensions=[pkg], size=100000000},
>   ccats={extensions=[pdf], size=100000000},
>   product-archive={extensions=[pkg], size=100000000},
>   developer-id-package={extensions=[zip, pkg, dmg], size=100000000},
>   bundle={extensions=[zip, ipa], size=100000000},
>   large-icon={extensions=[jpg, png, jpeg], size=100000000}}
>
> [2018-11-28 09:39:13 PST]  DBG-X:   parameter ErrorMessage =
>   ERROR ITMS-90596: "Invalid Bundle. The asset catalog at
>   'Payload/***.app/Assets.car' can't be processed. Rebuild your app, and
>   all included extensions and frameworks, with the latest GM version of
>   Xcode and resubmit. (1102)
>
> [2018-11-28 09:39:13 PST]  DBG-X:   parameter Success = false
>
> [2018-11-28 09:39:13 PST]  ERROR: ERROR ITMS-90596: "Invalid
>   Bundle. The asset catalog at 'Payload/***.app/Assets.car' can't be
>   processed. Rebuild your app, and all included extensions and
>   frameworks, with the latest GM version of Xcode and resubmit."
>
> [2018-11-28 09:39:13 PST]  DBG-X: The error code is: 1102
>
> [2018-11-28 09:39:13 PST]   INFO: Done performing
>   authentication.
>
> [2018-11-28 09:39:13 PST]  DBG-X: Returning 1

XML snip:

```
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-8.0.0" />
  <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />

  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification" />
  <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" />
  <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" />
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
  <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
  <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
  <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
  <preference name="Fullscreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i solutioned it installing de last version of XCode 10.1 that includes Aplicattion Launcher 3.7.2.

Using this version of Aplicattion Launcher disappeared this error message.

I hope this help you.